# Search Google Places on tableView when textField is clicked in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, google-places

How to Search `Google Places` when i click on `textField`and want to show results just below `textField`. I am using Swift 3.0 version.Could someone help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to install the GooglePlaces SDK in your project. Then you refer the code bellow.

**in Swift 3**

In AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlacePicker

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    func setUpGoogleMaps()
    return true
}

func setUpGoogleMaps() {
    let googleMapsApiKey = "AIzaSyA-kiOBvrR9CNztqutwmKaSLyXIid93K0E"
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyA-kiOBvrR9CNztqutwmKaSLyXIid93K0E")
}
```

In your ViewController which is having the textField

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlacePicker

class HotelVC: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var YourTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.YourTextField.delegate = self

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    self.present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}


extension viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress ?? "null")")
    self.YourTextField.text = place.formattedAddress
    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    //        print("Error: \(error.description)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    print("Autocomplete was cancelled.")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro it worked for me forgot to up vote @Gregory Wilson Pullyattu

Answer (score 3):

You will get location from the selected place. Try this code.

```
public func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
var lat = place.coordinate.latitude
var lon = place.coordinate.longitude
print("lat lon",lat,lon)

}
```